# Trying to get a job to stop itself from running

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to get a job to stop itself from running. The same code works when starting a new job.

I get the error:

`Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: Requested entity was not found. at callErrorFromStatus`

Following code

```
const endJob = async () => {
  try {
    const runClient = new JobsClient({
      projectId: getProjectId(),
      credentials: {
        client_email: env.gcloudClientEmail,
        private_key: env.gcloudPrivateKey,
      },
    });

    const jobName = process.env.CLOUD_RUN_EXECUTION;
    console.log(`Ending job ${jobName}`);


    // Run request
    const [operation] = await runClient.deleteJob({
      name: `projects/${getProjectId()}/locations/europe-west1/jobs/${jobName}`
    });
    const [response] = await operation.promise();
    
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Failed to endJob');
    console.error(e);
  }
};
```

Comment: Please follow SO guidelines on titles of questions. [ask] Do not put tags in title. Write a descriptive title.

Comment: It's a rule. From the [ask] link I gave you: "Don't include tags in the title. The system will automatically prepend the most important tag to your title for search-engine optimization purposes. You don't need to (and shouldn't) do it manually."